# Is it possible to parse a property from application.yml to the java class field with a different name?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parsing, yaml

Is it possible to parse a property from application.yml to the java class field with a different name?

Say I have the following `application.yml` file

```
service:
  cms:
    webClient: http://www.example.com
```

and my java class is

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.cms")
public class CmsProperties {
  private String webClient;
}
```

I would like to rename java field name `CmsProperties#webClient` into `CmsProperties#basePath`, but I must keep the original name `webClient` in the `application.yml`.

Is it possible to do it?

P.S. I am using Spring Framework if it matters for the solution.

Comment: Do you use spring framework?

Comment: Yes, I do use Spring Framework. I have also just added it to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OfCourse It is possible.

**Spring**

When you read property from yml file, you just need to provide key while it stores in basePath

```
@Value("${webClient}")
private String basePath;
```

**Plain Java**

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("path/to/config.properties")) {
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(input);
String basePath = prop.getProperty("webClient")
```

Hope that does resolve answer

Comment: Thank you. That is valid. Though it did not really works for me as I oversimplified the question. I decided not to edit this question as you have already answered it.  I reformulated it in a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316777/how-to-match-a-class-property-from-application-yml-to-the-java-class-with-a-diff