# How to match a class property from application.yml to the java class with a different class name?

Tags: java, spring, parsing, yaml

I am using Spring Framework and need to match a **class** property from application.yml to the java class with a different **class** name?

I have the following application.yml file:

```
service:
  cms:
    webClient:
      basePath: http://www.example.com
      connectionTimeoutSeconds: 3
      readTimeoutSeconds: 3
    url:
      path: /some/path/
      parameters:
        tree: basic
    credential:
      username: misha
      password: 123
```

and my java class for `service.cms` properties:

```
// block A: It already works

@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.cms")
public class CmsProperties {
  private WebClientProperties webClient; // I want rename it to webClientProperties
  private UrlProperties url;
  private CredentialProperties credential;
}
```

where `WebClientProperties` is

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebClientProperties {
  private String basePath;
  private int connectionTimeoutSeconds;
  private int readTimeoutSeconds;
}
```

I would like to rename java field name `CmsProperties#webClient` into `CmsProperties#WebClientProperties`, but I must keep the original name `webClient` in the application.yml.
Just using `@Value` over `CmsProperties#webClient` does not work:

```
//Block B: `webClient` name is changed to `WebClientProperties`. 
// This what I want - but it did not work! 

@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.cms")
public class CmsProperties {
  @Value("${webClient}")
  private WebClientProperties webClientProperties; // Name changed to `webClientProperties`
  ...
}
```

I have errors:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'webClient' in value "${webClient}"
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Renaming of webClient to webClientProperties, won't be possible as spring is looking for matching name. @Value read String value while **webClient** is not a string. So it does throw exception to you.

Comment: The solution is found. See `@bdshadow`'s answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, take a look at a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960921/spring-boot-configurationproperties-change-property-key/52961096)

So you don't need `@Value("${webClient}")`. Just create a setter:

```java
public void setWebClient(WebClientProperties webClient) {
    this.webClientProperties = webClient;
}
```

Comment: So simple - and so helpful! It what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, below code will work

**Parent Property class**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.cms")
public class PropertyReader {

    public WebClient webClient;
}
```

---

**Child Property Class**

```
//GETTER SETTER removed 
public class WebClient {

@Value("${basePath}")
private String basePath;
@Value("${connectionTimeoutSeconds}")
private String connectionTimeoutSeconds;
@Value("${readTimeoutSeconds}")
private String readTimeoutSeconds;
}
```

**application.yml**

```
service:   
  cms:
    webClient:
      basePath: http://www.example.com
      connectionTimeoutSeconds: 3
      readTimeoutSeconds: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but this is not what I need. Child Property Class `WebClientProperties` should not be changed, only its variable name `webClient` --> `webClientProperties`. plz see the question - I added the comments to code. I hope that will help to understand the question need more clearly.

Comment: I replied, please check